# Symfony 3 Relation concept

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.1, symfony-3.2

i am new and  some confused during create relation between entities (one to many) in symfony.i have make the relation in entity files but no any foreign key created .  According to http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html
can i modify only entity class (src/AppBundle/Entity/Category.php) or orm file also(# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Category.orm.yml) .

Comment: Are you using annotations like @ORM\something in your entity file?  If so then you need to delete any files under Resources/config/doctrine.  You can use either annotations or yaml but not both at the same time.

Comment: oneToMany not create any foreign key but manyToOne does. see this link for  more details: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: if i use annotation configuration for entity then hows database  table create